# Open Graph tags not working for sub pages of React App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, share-open-graph

I am using an AWS S3 bucket to serve up a react web app (sits behind an AWS cloudfront distribution) which is pointed to by a hosted zone in route53. I have configured OG tags in the index.html page, and they are working perfectly when sharing `https://www.myexampledomain.com`. However when I share a sub page such as `https://www.myexampledomain.com/example` the OG data is not being found (aka when sharing on whatsapp). When testing the app here: https://www.opengraph.xyz/ it says it's receiving 404 on the sub pages.

What I have done so far:

1. I have configured my S3 bucket error page to redirect to index.html.
2. I have checked that the OG tags are included in the sub pages (by using the inspect feature on google chrome)
3. I have curled the sub pages and confirm that I get 200 responses when curling the page, and also it includes the OG tags in the head section

I am unsure why the OG tags are not being found when sharing on WhatsApp ect. I am unsure if it's a AWS issue or React issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!